# Is it possible for a digital certificate to expire before its expiry date?

Tags: java, ssl, certificate

Our secure SMTP connection to an external site began failing on 4/22. The error message indicated an issue somewhere in the certificate chain.

```
[java:java:ERR /1:to_RHIO_direct_0:--/--/---- --:--:--] org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
[java:java:ERR /1:to_RHIO_direct_0:--/--/---- --:--:--]   nested exception is:
[java:java:ERR /1:to_RHIO_direct_0:--/--/---- --:--:--]      javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
```

We make the connection first, then issue Start TLS. This has been working without problems for over two years. Two years ago, maybe 27 months ago, we had a similar issue - same exception in the log. I did not keep records of that issue but I remember that the digital certificate had an expiry date that was one week in the future - that is, it should have been working for one more week before any problems arose because of expiry. So last time, we got a new certificate and the problem was resolved.
So this time, I observed the same circumstance. The expiry date on that certificate was for 4/29/2022:

```
Keystore type: jks
Keystore provider: IBMJCE

Your keystore contains 2 entries

Alias name: (identifying information removed)
Creation date: Mar 13, 2020
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: (identifying information removed)
Issuer: CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
Serial number: (identifying information removed)
Valid from: 2/27/20 7:00 PM until: 4/29/22 8:00 AM
```

So one might say, that is just a coincidence, the certificate is still good for another week and the problem must come from elsewhere.
Well, yesterday the vendor sent me an updated version of the same certificate, and when I added it to the truststore, the connection was established successfully. So, the only change I made was to replace the certificate.
Possibly there was an issue with a CA higher up in the chain? And the certificate I received referenced a newer version of a CA higher up in the chain?
That is all I can think of.. but it is very strange that the same circumstances happened twice and  the resolution both times was to replace a certificate that had not yet expired.
Is there another explanation? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Possibly there was an issue with a CA higher up in the chain? And the certificate I received referenced a newer version of a CA higher up in the chain?

Yeah probably. Usually there is not so much 'the certificate' as 'the certificate *chain*'. What you showed is merely the final certificate in the chain. If any one of the certs in that chain expired on 4/22/22, then, you have your answer.

Alternatively, it's of course possible your server's clock is wildly off (by 7 days).

Comment: I have to cross off the alternative where the server clock is off by a week.. So thank you for confirming.